# Converting complex dictionary to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am looking into Pythonian ways of extracting part of the dictionary below and turning it into a pandas DataFrame as shown. Appreciate your help with that!

```
{'data': [{'x': {'name': 'Gamma', 'unit': 'cps', 'values': [10, 20, 30]},
   'y': {'name': 'Depth', 'unit': 'm', 'values': [34.3, 34.5, 34.7]}}]}
```

|  | Depth | Gamma |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34.3 | 10 |
| 2 | 34.4 | 20 |
| 3 | 34.5 | 30 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, basically, you need to iterate over the values of each dict in the `'data'` list, which is itself a dict of column information:

```
In [1]: data = {'data': [{'x': {'name': 'Gamma', 'unit': 'cps', 'values': [10, 20, 30]},
   ...:    'y': {'name': 'Depth', 'unit': 'm', 'values': [34.3, 34.5, 34.7]}}]}

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: pd.DataFrame({
   ...:     col["name"]: col["values"]
   ...:     for d in data['data']
   ...:     for col in d.values()
   ...: })
Out[3]:
   Gamma  Depth
0     10   34.3
1     20   34.5
2     30   34.7
```